# Mask and modify 8-byte signal from FPGA serial communication

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, mask, bit

I struggle with creating a mask to only write certain bits of my data.
Currently i read 32bit data over serial. After reading i get the following information:

```
b'rt 00000000\n'
```

This has the type bytes. I assume, my 32bit from a certain register get converted to 8 bytes. However, this register has multiple fields, lets say field1 ranges from bit 0 to 4, field2 from bit 4 to 5, field3 from bit 5 to 8 and so on, so they vary in number, length and position, depending on the register. Now i want to read the information, apply a mask over a certain field, modify that field, and write the information back to my serial device. I have written additional functions to get information of the number of fields, fieldoffsets and fieldwidths.
What i have achieved so far:

```
    read_value = read_register_byte(s, r, regName) #output: '00000000'
    #from hex to int
    read_value = int(read_value, 16)
    #from int to 32bit-bin without prefix
    read_value = format(read_value, '032b')

    #define mask range
    maskStart = len(read_value) - (offsets[fieldNo] + widths[fieldNo]) #for field0 this results in 28
    maskStop = len(read_value) - offsets[fieldNo] #this results in 32

    #create mask template (32bit)
    mask = [0]*32
    j = 0
    #insert F for mask range
    for i in read_value:
        mask[j] = read_value[j]
        if j >= maskStart and j < maskStop:
            mask[j]='F'
        j+=1
    #to string
    tempMask=""
    for i in mask:
        tempMask += i
    mask = tempMask
```

```
read_value
Out[96]: '00000000000000000000000000000000'

mask
Out[97]: '0000000000000000000000000000FFFF'
```

What im trying to do is to allow only modification of those bits marked with F. Im sure this is very bad practise, however it should work if i could only achieve the following steps: manipulate read_value with my mask, convert my data back to that 8-byte format and write to my serial-device.

Edit:

```
Field = namedtuple("Field", ["pos_lsb", "width"])
REG_WIDTH = 32 #r.width
REG_HEX_DIGITS = REG_WIDTH // 4

def create_mask(pos_lsb, width):
    mask = ((1 << width)-1) << pos_lsb
    return mask

def get_field(reg_value, field):
    mask = create_mask(*field)
    field_value = (reg_value & mask) >> field.pos_lsb
    return field_value

def set_field(reg_value, field, new_value):
    mask = create_mask(*field)
    reg_value = (reg_value & ~mask) | (new_value << field.pos_lsb)
    return reg_value

def value_from_string(reg_value_string):
    return int(reg_value_string, 16)

def value_to_string(reg_value):
    return f"{reg_value:0{REG_HEX_DIGITS}X}"

def write_field(s, r, regName, fieldNo, data):
    """ Writes to a single field of a Trixel register """
    """ debug block """
    # s = open_serial_port()
    # r = Registermap()
    # regName = 'tcm_control'
    # fieldNo = 0 #1st field
    # data = 5
    """ end of debug block """

    regAddress = r.get_register_address(regName)
    fields = r.get_register(regName, 'fields')
    offsets = r.get_register(regName, 'offsets')
    widths = r.get_register(regName, 'widths')

    if fieldNo+1 > fields:
        print('fieldNo out of range (max fields: ' + str(fields) + '). Aborting..')
        return 0

    fieldStart = r.baseAddress + regAddress + offsets[fieldNo]
    addr = r.baseAddress + regAddress
    register_value_string = read_register_byte(s, r, regName)
    field = Field(pos_lsb=offsets[fieldNo], width=widths[fieldNo])
    new_field_value = data

    # Update field
    print("Register: " + str(regName) + ", fieldNo: " + str(fieldNo+1) + "(" + str(fieldNo) + ")" + ", offset (hex): " + hex(fieldStart))
    print("Fieldname: " + str(r.get_register(regName,'descriptions')[fieldNo]))
    print(f"Original register value: {register_value_string}")
    reg_val = value_from_string(register_value_string)
    field_value = get_field(reg_val, field)
    print(f"Original field value: {field_value} (0x{field_value:x} in hex)")
    print(f"Setting field to {new_field_value} (0x{new_field_value:x} in hex)")
    reg_val = set_field(reg_val, field, new_field_value)
    field_value = get_field(reg_val, field)
    print(f"New field value: {field_value} (0x{field_value:x} in hex)")
    new_reg_val_string = value_to_string(reg_val)
    print(f"New register value to write to FPGA: {new_reg_val_string}")

    #write to FPGA
    cmd = ("mwr {:08X}".format(addr) + " " + new_reg_val_string + " \n").encode()
    message = s.write(cmd)

    if message != len(cmd):
        print('Error in Write! Bytes expected: ' + str(len(cmd)) + ', written: ' + str(message) + ', cmd: ' + str(cmd))
    elif message == len(cmd):
        print('Write to register ' + str(hex(addr)) + ' OK.')
```

Working example:

```
write_field(s, r, 'tcm_control', 3, 1)
Register: tcm_control, fieldNo: 4(3), offset (hex): 0x50000406
Fieldname: Should be released after configuring all TCM registers over AXI
Original register value: 00000071
Original field value: 1 (0x1 in hex)
Setting field to 1 (0x1 in hex)
New field value: 1 (0x1 in hex)
New register value to write to FPGA: 00000071
Write to register 0x50000400 OK.
```

Failing example:

```
write_field(s, r, 'tcm_control', 3, 2)
Register: tcm_control, fieldNo: 4(3), offset (hex): 0x50000406
Fieldname: Should be released after configuring all TCM registers over AXI
Original register value: 00000071
Original field value: 1 (0x1 in hex)
Setting field to 2 (0x2 in hex)
New field value: 0 (0x0 in hex)
New register value to write to FPGA: 000000B1
Write to register 0x50000400 OK.

read_register_byte(s, r, 'tcm_control')
Out[15]: '00000031'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are approaching this the wrong way. Please have a look at this (not very commented) code and see if that is what you actually wants:

```
from collections import namedtuple

REG_WIDTH = 32
REG_HEX_DIGITS = REG_WIDTH // 4


Field = namedtuple("Field", ["pos_lsb", "width"])


def create_mask(pos_lsb, width):
    mask = ((1 << width)-1) << pos_lsb
    return mask


def get_field(reg_value, field):
    mask = create_mask(*field)
    field_value = (reg_value & mask) >> field.pos_lsb
    return field_value


def set_field(reg_value, field, new_value):
    mask = create_mask(*field)
    reg_value = (reg_value & ~mask) | (new_value << field.pos_lsb)
    return reg_value


def value_from_string(reg_value_string):
    return int(reg_value_string, 16)


def value_to_string(reg_value):
    return f"{reg_value:0{REG_HEX_DIGITS}X}"


register_value_string = "0F00F0FF"
field1 = Field(pos_lsb=3, width=5)
new_field_value = 0x12

# Update field1.
print(f"Original register value: {register_value_string}")
reg_val = value_from_string(register_value_string)
field_value = get_field(reg_val, field1)
print(f"Original field value: {field_value} (0x{field_value:x} in hex)")
print(f"Setting field to {new_field_value} (0x{new_field_value:x} in hex)")
reg_val = set_field(reg_val, field1, new_field_value)
field_value = get_field(reg_val, field1)
print(f"New field value: {field_value} (0x{field_value:x} in hex)")
new_reg_val_string = value_to_string(reg_val)
print(f"New register value to write to FPGA: {new_reg_val_string}")
```

Output:

```
Original register value: 0F00F0FF
Original field value: 31 (0x1f in hex)
Setting field to 18 (0x12 in hex)
New field value: 18 (0x12 in hex)
New register value to write to FPGA: 0F00F097
```

I believe this is more in line with what you would want. If you want me to explain it further, please let me know.

Comment: Hey JohanL, thanks alot for your advice! Really nice code, thats exactly what im trying to do. Im trying to implement your code at the moment, do i have to write to my base register address when writing a register, because i am sending the whole 32 bit anyway, no matter what field im addressing? Or do i have to add the field offset to my register offset. Also i've noticed, that under some circumstances the line New field value: X provides other results than the line Setting field to X. I edited my code. I guess i made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Whether you can write a single field or need to update the whole register depends on your FPGA implementation and if you allow masked writes (in which case you typically need to send the mask as well). My guess is that your system require a full register write (or potentially, but less likely, you have byte masks, masking 8 bits at a time). If you do send a full 32 bit word, you should send it to the base address, as you assume.

Comment: Your failing example is due to you writing a larger value than the field can hold. From the error it can be deduced that the field `'tcm_control'`is onlye one bit wide, but you try to write a two bit value (`0b10`). Since my code does not provide any error checking, the write will be allowed, however overflow into the next field, but when reading back, the out-of-bounds data will not be read back. That is why you see a discrepancy between what you write and what you read back.